# Unable to run logstash with file configuration on docker

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am trying to run the ELK stack using docker. But unfortunately, logstash container is not running and I am unable to find the exact error why it's failing.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:7.9.2
        ports:
          - '9200:9200'
        networks:
          - elk
        environment:
          - discovery.type=single-node
          - xpack.security.enabled=false
        ulimits:
          memlock:
            soft: -1
            hard: -1
          nofile:
            soft: 65536
            hard: 65536
        
          
    logstash:
        image: logstash:7.9.2
        ports:
          - '5000:5000'
        networks:
          - elk        
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
            target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
            read_only: true
          - type: bind
            source: ./logstash/pipeline
            target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
            read_only: true
        
        depends_on:
          - elasticsearch
    
networks:
    elk:
      driver: bridge
```

logstash.yml

```
---
## Default Logstash configuration from Logstash base image.
## https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/docker/data/logstash/config/logstash-full.yml
#
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://elasticsearch:9200" ]

## X-Pack security credentials
#
xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: elastic
#xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: changeme
```

logstash.conf

```
input{
    file{
        path => "C:\Users\User1\Downloads\library-mgmt-system-logs\user-service\user-service.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "library-mgmt-system-logstash-index"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
    }
}
```

logstash shutdown logs:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper (file:/tmp/jruby-1/jruby280139731768845147jopenssl.jar) to field java.security.MessageDigest.provider
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.jruby.ext.openssl.SecurityHelper
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-08-01T08:42:44,135][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.8+10-LTS on 11.0.8+10-LTS +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:44,172][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/queue"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:44,184][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:44,578][INFO ][logstash.agent ] No persistent UUID file found. Generating new UUID {:uuid=>"b15dc5df-3deb-4698-aa37-e114a733bfa9", :path=>"/usr/share/logstash/data/uuid"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:45,186][WARN ][deprecation.logstash.monitoringextension.pipelineregisterhook] Internal collectors option for Logstash monitoring is deprecated and targeted for removal in the next major version.
Please configure Metricbeat to monitor Logstash. Documentation can be found at:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-with-metricbeat.html
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,007][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,306][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,394][INFO ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,399][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,642][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Monitoring License OK
[2021-08-01T08:42:46,644][INFO ][logstash.monitoring.internalpipelinesource] Validated license for monitoring. Enabling monitoring pipeline.
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,382][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 32 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 22 keys and 45 values
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,706][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,706][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,725][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,725][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,736][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,736][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,736][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,736][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,785][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearchmonitoring][.monitoring-logstash] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearchMonitoring", :hosts=>["http://elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,788][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//elasticsearch:9200"]}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,793][WARN ][logstash.javapipeline ][.monitoring-logstash] 'pipeline.ordered' is enabled and is likely less efficient, consider disabling if preserving event order is not necessary
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,833][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,879][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ][.monitoring-logstash] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>".monitoring-logstash", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>2, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>2, "pipeline.sources"=>["monitoring pipeline"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0xb20b7c7@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipelines_registry.rb:141 run>"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,888][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x62ff495a@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:122 run>"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,901][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2021-08-01T08:42:48,931][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Installing elasticsearch template to _template/logstash
[2021-08-01T08:42:49,686][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.81}
[2021-08-01T08:42:49,688][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ][main] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>0.8}
[2021-08-01T08:42:49,730][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ][.monitoring-logstash] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:50,840][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2021-08-01T08:42:51,147][INFO ][logstash.agent ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-08-01T08:42:53,108][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline ] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>".monitoring-logstash"}
[2021-08-01T08:42:53,162][INFO ][logstash.runner ] Logstash shut down.
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. Please refer the below updated files

docker-compose.yaml

```
logstash:
        image: logstash:7.13.4
        ports:
          - '5000:5000'
        networks:
          - elk        
        volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
            target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
            read_only: true
          - type: bind
            source: ./logstash/pipeline
            target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
            read_only: true
          - type: bind
            source: C:/Users/Rupesh_Patil/Desktop/logstash-data
            target: /usr/share/logs/
            read_only: true        
        depends_on:
          - elasticsearch
```

logstash.conf

```
input{
    file{
        type=>"user"
        path=>"/usr/share/logs/user-service/user-service.log"
        start_position=>"beginning"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "library-mgmt-system-logstash-index"
        ecs_compatibility => disabled
    }
}
```